# how do I extract the numbers from before and after a symbol in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the number that is before a symbol and the number after the symbol.

Example:

```
String=ajdje782@29sjdjn
```

I want a variable with the number `782` and a variable with `29`.

The numbers can be any length and there can be any number of letters. The symbol may be between 3 or 4 different symbols.

I tried using for loops to find the start and end of each  side and store them, but it got too complicated and I couldn't understand it

Comment: An easy solution may be: `'ajdje782@29sjdjn'.split(/\D/).filter(Boolean)`. But you need to be more specific on the regularity of your input in order to provide a more general answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `match()` operator:

```js
const s = 'String=ajdje782@29sjdjn';
const [var1, var2] = s.match(/\d+/g);
console.log(`var1=${var1} var2=${var2}`);
```

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `\d+` | digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |

The `g` modifiers in `//g` meant *all matches*.

Comment: Is this specific to NodeJS? What makes it incompatible with browsers?

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina it is not incompatible with browser JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, NodeJS is just an interactive JS shell, can be done everywhere in vanilla JS